# Firebase: is there any observer to watch for change in email verification status?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My Single page VueJs web app needs to know when a Firebase user's Email verification status changes.

Problem: When the user clicks on the email on the link to verify his email, after successfully completing the process, he is sent to another browser tab, thus another instance of the app. There I can reload the user and get the correct email verification status.... but that won't affect the initial app in other browser tabs.

So, is there any watcher who will observe this email verification status change live?

I tried:

```
firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged( function ( user ) {
  if ( user ) {
    console.log( "onIdTokenChanged" );
  }
} );
```

But apparently, the email verification status doesn't cause a token change.

I can deal with this with localStorage and Vuejs magic but that would be cumbersome.

Comment: Aside from my answer, here is a [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) where I explained that. It's for Android, but the same thing applies to all platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, is there any watcher who will observe this email verification status change live?

No, there is not. The email verification happens outside the app, so when you click the link in the email in the other tab, there is nothing built-in that triggers Firebase Authentication clients to be updated. So there is **no** callback for that. Firebase Authentication only refreshes the ID token once per hour. This means that it may take up to an hour before the token is refreshed. In this case the `onIdTokenChanged()` method fires. Unfortunately, `onAuthStateChanged()` nor `onIdTokenChanged()` fires when the link is clicked, which basically means that we have to check that in our application code, on demand. There is a `.reload()` function that can help you with that.